# FireFox menus became double-spaced in latest update - I want to return to single-spaced. How can I do this?

Tags: firefox

In the last couple of days, FireFox's bookmark menus have become double-spaced. I believe the double-spacing also applies to the context menus.

[image: screenshot]

This was posted in the [now-closed question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795063/new-firefox-update-menu-bookmark-padding-spacing-fix). Here is the [Mozilla forum question on the topic](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1337967).

I have tried the suggestions posted there without success.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. This is a horrible design change, we now have less data and more fluff on the screen. BTW the *browser.proton.contextmenus.enabled* fix worked for me

Comment: After another try, the *browser.proton.contextmenus.enabled = false* fix worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me what worked was the CSS from https://www.userchrome.org/firefox-89-styling-proton-ui.html:

- Go to or create Userchrome.css (as per previous answer need to go to "C:\Users\(my_name)\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles". Look for the newest folder, go into it and find the folder called 'chrome'. If the 'chrome' folder doesn't exist, create it.
- Open userChrome.css in Notepad. (you may need to create this as well)
- Enter the following

```
menupopup > menuitem, menupopup > menu {
  padding-block: 4px !important;
}
:root {
  --arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 4px 8px !important;
}
```

- Restart firefox

If this does not work then:

- Go to about:config in a browser tab and accept the warning
- Search for `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` and set it to true
- Restart firefox

Comment: Just did it again! August 2021. Your second alternative of setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to True worked.  Thank you.

Comment: This is unnecessary, just set `browser.proton.contextmenus.enabled` to `false` in `about:config` and you're done.

Comment: @pigeonburger See my answer below. But that does not work in the latest update.

Comment: I've added my current solution to this issue, see my new answer.

Comment: They did it again! Currently about space-and-a-half instead of double space! Is this a monthly thing?

Answer (score 2):

### For me the *browser.proton.contextmenus.enabled = false* fix worked

1. In the browser address bar, type `about:config`.
2. Search for "browser.proton" to get a list.
3. Disable **Browser.Proton.Contextmenus.enabled**

[image: screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of the same menus after this was done:

[image: screenshot of fixed menus]

Comment: This worked in older versions, but seems to not work anymore - tested on FF 91.0.1

Comment: See my note to Lesma's answer. Second suggestion made worked for me this time. I sure wish the developers would stop doing this!

Answer (score 1):

I had previously fixed this problem back in June, 2021. I followed the instructions found at https://www.ghacks.net/2021/05/09/how-to-fix-the-firefox-89-user-interface/ to download the 2 .css files stored on their website. Today, Jan 25,2022, I found that my FF browser (96.0.2 version) had reverted back to double spacing (as well as the File, Edit, View etc. pull downs). I tried all of the above methods and nothing worked for me. I went back to the "ghacks" web page noted above and saw that their 2 .css files had been recently updated. I downloaded their latest files, replaced my old userChrome.css and userContent.css files and restarted FF. Success!

Comment: Thank you. I tried this method and did not get any improvement. It is still better than the default settings, but is at an intermediate level.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. This worked (from https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1186601):

- Find the latest profile that FF just created. Mine was in "C:\Users\(my_name)\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles". Look for the newest folder, go into it and find the folder called 'chrome'. If the 'chrome' folder doesn't exist, create it.
- Open userChrome.css in Notepad. (If you had to create the 'chrome' folder, create this file as well).
- Paste this at the bottom of the file:

```
/* Bookmark menu */
#PlacesToolbarItems .bookmark-item {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

/* Right-click menu */
menupopup#contentAreaContextMenu menu,
menupopup#contentAreaContextMenu menuitem {
  padding-top:0px !important;
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
}
```

- Save the file and restart FF.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This solution offers the *closest* resemblance to the old Firefox style, and is what I use (you'll notice that the `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css` are too big to paste here so I've linked to where I found them:

1. Go to `about:config` and set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `false`.
2. Then go to `about:support` and press "Open Folder" under "Profile Folder".
3. In the folder that opens up, create a new folder called `chrome`, and inside it, copy both the `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css` from [here](https://github.com/BGMP/firefox-revert-proton/tree/trunk/normal).
4. Restart Firefox, and you'll have all the menus normally spaced, and your old style of Firefox back!

Comment: For me, this time, this took me from space-and-a-half to double-spaced!

Comment: That's odd, because I'm using those exact same files on the latest version of Firefox as I type this, and it's normal

Comment: Setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `false` will double-space my menus.

Comment: Again, I am still using this exact same answer to keep Firefox as it once was, and it works as intended. I even just set up a new profile from scratch and followed these instructions and it still works as intended. Try setting up a new blank Firefox profile with all the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

March 2023: This suddenly happened to me after a debian update to firefox version: 102.8.0esr

There's a "compact mode" which returns the menus to usable spacing, as well as making the bookmarks toolbar thinner.

But even the option to do so is hidden and you need to go through about:config to turn the option back on

Instructions here worked for me:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/compact-mode-workaround-firefox

Comment: Thank you for supplying this. I will probably come back when they do it to me again.